# Why does the page fault not cause the thread to finish its execution later?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, cpu-architecture, page-fault

I have the below code where I'm intentionally creating a page fault in one of the threads in `file.c`

`util.c`

```c
#include "util.h"

// to use as a fence() instruction
extern inline __attribute__((always_inline))
CYCLES rdtscp(void) {
    CYCLES cycles;
    asm volatile ("rdtscp" :  "=a" (cycles));

    return cycles;
}

// initialize address
void init_ram_address(char* FILE_NAME){
    char *filename = FILE_NAME;
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1) {
        printf("Could not open file .\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    void *file_address = mmap(NULL, DEFAULT_FILE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_POPULATE, fd, 0);
    ram_address = (int *) file_address;
}

// initialize address
void init_disk_address(char* FILE_NAME){
    char *filename = FILE_NAME;
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1) {
        printf("Could not open file .\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    void *file_address = mmap(NULL, DEFAULT_FILE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    disk_address = (int *) file_address;
}
```

`file.c`

```c
#include "util.h"

void *f1();
void *f2();

pthread_barrier_t barrier;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pthread_t t1, t2;

    // in ram
    init_ram_address(RAM_FILE_NAME);
    // in disk
    init_disk_address(DISK_FILE_NAME);

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &f1, NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2, NULL, &f2, NULL);

    
    pthread_join(t1, NULL);
    pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    
    return 0;
}

void *f1()
{
    rdtscp();
    int load = *(ram_address);
    rdtscp();
    printf("Expecting this to be run first.\n");
}

void *f2()
{
    rdtscp();
    int load = *(disk_address);
    rdtscp();
    printf("Expecting this to be run second.\n");
}
```

I've used `rdtscp()` in the above code for fencing purposes (to ensure that the print statement get executed only after the load operation is done).

Since `t2` will incur a page fault, I expect `t1` to finish executing its print statement first.

To run both the threads on the same core, I run `taskset -c 10 ./file`.

I see that `t2` prints its statement before `t1`. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're expecting `t2`'s `int load = *(disk_address);` to cause a context switch to `t1`, and since you're pinning everything to the same CPU core, that would give `t1` time to win the race to take the lock for `stdout`.

**A soft page fault doesn't need to context-switch**, just update the page tables with a file page from the pagecache.  Despite the mapping being backed by a disk file, not anonymous memory or just copy-on-write tricks, if the the file has been read or written recently it will be hot in the pagecache and not require I/O (which would make it a *hard* page fault).

Maybe try evicting disk cache before a test run, like with `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` if this is Linux, so access to the mmap region without `MAP_POPULATE` will be a *hard* page fault (requiring I/O).

(See *https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17936/setting-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-to-clear-cache*; `sync` first, at least on the disk file, if it was recently written, to make sure it's page(s) are clean and able to be evicted aka dropped.  Dropping caches is mainly useful for benchmarking.)

---

Or programmatically, you can *hint* the kernel with the [`madvise(2)` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), like `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)` on a page, encouraging it to evict it from pagecache soon.  (Or at least hint that your process doesn't need it; other processes might keep it hot).

In Linux kernel 5.4 and later, `MADV_COLD` works as a hint to evict the specified page(s) on memory pressure.  ("Deactivate" probably means remove from HW page tables, so next access will at least be a soft page fault.) Or **`MADV_PAGEOUT`** is apparently supposed to get the kernel to reclaim the specified page(s) right away, I guess before the system call returns.  After that, the next access should be a hard page fault.

> - `MADV_COLD` (since Linux 5.4)
>   Deactivate a given range of pages.  This will make the pages a more probable reclaim target should there be a memory pressure.  This is a nondestructive operation.  The advice might be ignored for some pages in the range when it is not applicable.
> - **`MADV_PAGEOUT`** (since Linux 5.4)
>   **Reclaim  a  given  range  of  pages**.  This is done to free up memory occupied by these pages.  If a page is anonymous, it will be swapped out.  **If a page is file-backed and dirty, it will be written back to the backing storage.**  The advice might be ignored for some pages in the range when it is not applicable.

These `madvise` args are Linux-specific.  The `madvise` system call itself (as opposed to `posix_madvise`) is not guaranteed portable, but the man page gives the impression that some other systems have their own `madvise` system calls supporting some standard "advice" hints to the kernel.

---

You haven't shown the declaration of `ram_address` or `disk_address`.
If it's not a pointer-to-`volatile` like `volatile int *disk_address`, the loads may be optimized away at compile time.  Writes to non-escaped local vars like `int load` don't have to respect `"memory"` clobbers because nothing else could possibly have a reference to them.

If you compiled without optimization or something, then yes the load will still happen even without `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks, clearing the disk cache gave me the intended output.  Is there a a way to programmatically swap out the memory allocated by `mmap` to the disk? From what I understand, `munlock` unlocks the memory, but it is still up to the kernel whether to swap it out or not depending on the application's needs.

Comment: You can force writing to disk with `fsync`, but you can't easily force evicting the clean page from cache without that `/proc` interface, mainly useful for benchmarking.  You can *hint* the kernel with `madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)`.  Or in Linux 5.4 and later, `MADV_COLD` as a strong hint, or `MADV_PAGEOUT` is apparently supposed to get the kernel to reclaim the specified page(s) on the spot.  So actually there is an API for that. :)

Comment: I want to be able to run this application multiple times without running `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` every time. Is there a way to simply disable the page cache?

Comment: @SathvikSwaminathan: Like I wrote in my answer, `madvise(MADV_PAGEOUT)` should work for the specific pages you want.  What would disabling the pagecache even mean?  You wouldn't be to `mmap(MAP_SHARED)` anything, because that functionality is built on top of the pagecache.  Of course, so is `mmap(MAP_PRIVATE)` and even `execve` creating private mappings; probably only `open(O_DIRECT)` would work, but you might not be able to have a running executable in the first place. Or to put it another way, the pagecache is fundamental to how Linux manages file data. It's not "just a cache", not optional.